# How Could I count array's elements when they are greater than zero in Cypher?

Tags: arrays, graph, neo4j, count, cypher

How Could I count array's elements when they are greater than zero in Cypher?

```
With [12,-9,30,-5,4]
```

as a resault I would 3, how could I do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You say `2`, but should it not be `3` for `12`,`30`, and `4` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was wrong I meant 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this...

```
WITH [12,-9,30,-5,4] AS coll
RETURN filter(x IN coll WHERE x > 0) AS pos
```

and if you wanted the actual number of positive numbers

```
WITH [12,-9,30,-5,4] AS coll
RETURN size(filter(x IN coll WHERE x > 0)) AS pos
```

and as @christophewillemsen says

```
WITH [12,-9,30,-5,4] AS coll
RETURN size([x IN coll WHERE x > 0]) AS pos
```

Comment: You can also use python style list comprehension : `RETURN [x IN coll WHERE x > 0]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I did in this way and the result is correct:

```
 WITH [12,-9,30,-5,4] AS coll
 RETURN size(filter(x IN coll WHERE x > 0)) AS pos
```